# How to find and replace a substring?

Tags: java, android

For example I have such a string, in which I must find and replace multiple substrings, all of which start with `#`, contains 6 symbols, end with `'` and should not contain `)` ... what do you think would be the best way of achieving that?

Thanks!

Edit:
just one more thing I forgot, to make the replacement, I need that substring, i.e. it gets replaces by a string generated from the substring being replaced.

Comment: writing a regex and match it?

Comment: @Roger sounds like you have the pattern figured out - you should have a go at playing with regex using [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It's easier than you think!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yourNewText=yourOldText.replaceAll("#[^)]{6}'", "");
```

---

Or programmatically:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#[^)]{6}'").matcher(yourOldText);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()){
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, 
      // implement your custom logic here, matcher.group() is the found String
      someReplacement(matcher.group());
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
String yourNewString = sb. toString();
```

Comment: Don't forget the assignment of the result :)

Comment: just one more think I forgot, to make the replacement, I need that substring, i.e. it gets replaces by a string generated from the substring being replaced.

Comment: @Roger ok you should have said that before, that means you will have to do it programmatically. see my update

Comment: Yes, I thought of maybe making an array of those substring, then looping through them and replacing them in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just know the substrings are formatted like you explained above, but not exactly which 6 characters, try the following:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("#[^\\)]{6}'", "replacement"); //pattern to replace is #+6 characters not being ) + '
```

Comment: Thanks man, oh, just one more think I forgot, to make the replacement, I need that substring, i.e. it gets replaces by a string generated from the substring being replaced.

Comment: Is the escape inside the square brackets necessary?

Comment: @Sean they might not be necessary (at least I'm not sure) but I like to be consistent, i.e. if I have to escape them outside, I'd rather also escape them inside.

Answer (score 1):

this might not be the best way to do it but...

```
youstring = youstring.replace("#something'", "new stringx");
youstring = youstring.replace("#something2'", "new stringy");
youstring = youstring.replace("#something3'", "new stringz");
```

//edited after reading comments, thanks

Comment: If you don't actually use regex, you should use `String.replace()`, not `String.replaceAll()`

Comment: Don't forget to assign the result, i.e. your approach would lose the result of the replacement.

Comment: This seems like it could take an arbitrary amount of code if there's an arbitrary number of strings to replace.

Answer (score 1):

You must use replaceAll with the right regular expression:

```
myString.replaceAll("#[^)]{6}'", "something")
```

If you need to replace with an extract of the matched string, use a a match group, like this :

```
myString.replaceAll("#([^)]{6})'", "blah $1 blah")
```

the $1 in the second String matches the first parenthesed expression in the first String.

Comment: just one more think I forgot, to make the replacement, I need that substring, i.e. it gets replaces by a string generated from the substring being replaced.